# Parsing multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python and I need to write a program which determines the word which appears the most times in a poem. Problem which is troubling me is about parsing a lines of a poem into a SINGLE list containing words of the poem. When I solve it i will have no trouble determining the word which appears the most times.

I can access the lines of the poem by calling input() repeatedly, and the last line contains the three characters ###.

So, i wrote:

```
while True:
   y = input()
   if y == "###":
     break
   y = y.lower()
   y = y.split()
```

and for input:

```
Here is a line like sparkling wine
Line up now behind the cow
###
```

got result:

```
['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine']
['line', 'up', 'now', 'behind', 'the', 'cow']
```

If i try to call y[0], i get:

```
here
line
```

How can I concatenate two lists within same variable, or how can I assign every line to different variable?

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In general, reusing a variable name like this (`y` is variously a string, a lowercased string, and finally a list.) is a bad idea, as it makes your code more confusing. It would be better to write eg `inputline = input()`, `if inputline == "###":`, `lowercased = inputline.lower()`, `words = lowercased.split()`. If you don't do this kind of thing, you may often find that a variable contains something quite different than you thought when you scanned the code.

Comment: I know. Thank you. I just wanted to show the results of print asap, without saving original lines of input (y variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `y` to an existing list, using [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
words = []
while True:
   y = input()
   if y == "###":
     break
   y = y.lower()
   y = y.split()
   words.extend(y)
```

Now `words` is a list containing all the words of the lines your user entered.

Demo:

```
>>> words = []
>>> while True:
...    y = input()
...    if y == "###":
...      break
...    y = y.lower()
...    y = y.split()
...    words.extend(y)
... 
Here is a line like sparkling wine
Line up now behind the cow
###
>>> print(words)
['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine', 'line', 'up', 'now', 'behind', 'the', 'cow']
```

Comment: `append` seems more suitable here.

Comment: @Elazar: No, `y` is a list of words. The OP wanted *one* list of words, not a list of lists.

Comment: Program output with extend:

    ['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine']
    ['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine', 'line', 'up', 'now', 'behind', 'the', 'cow']                            I need one list.

Comment: @Reloader: Are printing `words` at the end of the loop, or are you printing `y` in the loop?

Comment: I am printing (words). It gives me two lines of output, consisting of two lists - ['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine']
['here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine', 'line', 'up', 'now', 'behind', 'the', 'cow']

Comment: @Reloader: You are printing `words` *inside* the loop. It shows you the list has grown for the second line. Move the print statement *outside* the loop. Look at the example I gave you.

Answer (score 3):

```
words = []

while True:
   y = input()
   if y == "###":
     break
   words.extend(y.lower().split())

from collections import Counter
Counter(words).most_common(1)
```

This whole code can be compressed into the following one liner:

```
Counter(y.lower() for x in iter(input, '###') for y in x.split()).most_common(1)
```

eg.

```
>>> sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO("""Here is a line like sparkling wine
Line up now behind the cow
###""")
>>> Counter(y.lower() for x in iter(input, '###') for y in x.split()).most_common(1)
[('line', 2)]
```

As per request, without any `import`s

```
c = {} # stores counts
for line in iter(input, '###'):
    for word in line.lower().split():
        c[word] = c.get(word, 0) + 1 # gets count of word or 0 if doesn't exist

print(max(c, key=c.get)) # gets max key of c, based on val (count)
```

To not have to make a second pass over the dictionary to find the max word, keep track of it as you go along:

```
c = {} # stores counts
max_word = None
for line in iter(input, '###'):
    for word in line.lower().split():
        c[word] = c.get(word, 0) + 1 # gets count of word or 0 if doesn't exist
        if max_word is None:
            max_word = word
        else:
            max_word = max(max_word, word, key=c.get) # max based on count       

print(max_word)
```

Comment: IMHO this code goes a little bit against the Zen of Python. I mean, I find it classy in some sort of sense, but it's quite cryptic. What do you think?

Comment: This code prints out correct answer, but I shouldn't use outside function to solve this problem. Only str.lower() and str.split() methods. Can it be done without importing the Counter function?

Comment: +1 for the `collections.Counter`solution. One might consider this _most pythonic_ by the virtue it is almost the exact same example provided in the [official documentation for `Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Comment: @Reloader added version with no imports

Comment: @Reloader Accept the answer you found most helpful to yourself ;)